# How to prevent plotly from plotting automatically

Tags: python, plotly

I just discovered plotly and like it so far. I have this code provided by the main website

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

trace0 = Scatter(
    x=[1,2,3,4],
    y=[10,15,13,17]
)
trace1 = Scatter(
    x=[1,2,3,4],
    y=[16,5,11,9]
)
data = Data([trace0, trace1])

unique_url = py.plot(data, filename='basic-line')
```

I am curious about two things:

1) When I run this code, my browser automatically pops up and shows me the graph. All I want is the url so that I can later embed it in an html file. Is there a way to turn off the feature that opens my browser and shows me the graph?

2) Is there a way to get rid of the 'Play with this data' link?

I have combed through the documentation provided, but have come up empty-handed on these two issues.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To disable pop-ups you could use `auto_open=FALSE` and try the following

```
py.plot(data, filename='basic_line', auto_open=False)
```

Comment: I will try that and get back to you. I wonder why I couldn't find that in the documentation.

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to remove the "play with this data" part

Comment: If it turns out that your suggestion prevents my browser from popping up, then I'll give you credit. I don't think I can test it until this evening, though. I wonder if setting `world_readable = false` would do the trick. My graphs are ultimately going into a pdf and the footnote is a bit of an eyesore and it won't even be functional in a pdf.

Comment: Andrew from Plotly here, Daniel's answer is correct to solve part 1, you should be able to see this with `help(py.plot)`. You cannot currently remove the 'play with this data'. You can do this in JS after-the-fact, but it's likely not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I didn't expect to elicit the response of a celebrity. Great. Thanks. I guess I need to pay more attention to the help files. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

`py.plot(data, show_link=False)` will take that link off (if you are referring to the link that says `Export to plot.ly`).  At least it does using:
`import plotly.offline as py`.  As for the link at the top (when you hover your mouse over the graph), I'm trying to get rid of the `Save and edit plot in cloud` but only find options for that under the java script version... and that hides the whole bar which has other useful items on it (javascript option is: `{displayModeBar: false}`). Obviously I am finding the reference to "play with this data" ambiguous.  You can see the workaround I wrote here: [Adding config modes to Plotly.Py offline - modebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554705/adding-config-modes-to-plotly-py-offline-modebar)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove that *Export to plot.ly* link in the offline graph.

Open your saved html file in a text editor. and search for. {"showLink": true, "linkText": "Export to plot.ly"}

And change the true value to false.