# Cast Plotly object to HTML and edit modeBar before plotting in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to edit the modeBarButtons of a plotly graph such that the 'save and edit plot in cloud' function becomes disabled. At first [this didn't seem possible in Python](https://community.plot.ly/t/disable-modebar-hover-tool/1347). But [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554705/adding-config-modes-to-plotly-py-offline-modebar) pointed out a workaround for Python, by casting the object to HTML and editing the HTML code.

Unfortunately, the 'save and edit plot in cloud' functionality remains when I try the example code below:

```
import numpy as np

from IPython.display import display, HTML

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

# create sin data to plot
x = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

# create plot data, edit and plot
trace0 = go.Scatter(x=x,y=y, name="Sin")
HTML_code = plot([trace0], show_link=False, auto_open=False, output_type='div')
HTML_code = HTML_code.replace('modeBarButtonsToRemove:[]',
   'modeBarButtonsToRemove:["sendDataToCloud"]')
display(HTML(HTML_code))
```

**[Edit]** Write to file:
The button is successfully removed when the edited HTML is written to file and opened in a browser.

Reloading the edited file into my notebook was unsuccessful:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
with open('./temp-plot.html', 'r') as file :
    tempHTML = file.read()
display(HTML(tempHTML))
```

> Javascript error adding output!
> ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined
> See your browser Javascript console for more details.

Using `output_type='div'` instead of `output_type='file'` (my preferred approach due to write restrictions for the final product):

The notebook seems to 'reload' plotlys' standard configuration and only insert the data from the HTML, leaving the edited JavaScript unused.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Koen